# DispatchSemaphore not waiting

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, dispatchsemaphore

In my command line app, DispatchSemaphore doesn't wait despite initializing to zero, decrementing with "wait" and incrementing with "signal". I don't want to use RunLoop.main.run().

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

func say(_ line: String) {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: line)
    synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    sema.signal() // increment
}

say("hello")
sema.wait()  // decrement
//RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: What is it supposed to be waiting for? All of that is synchronous code.

Comment: Your call to `signal`is made before the call to `wait`. `speak` does not block until the utterance is complete. Use the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` to know when the utterance is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AVSpeechSynthesizer.speak(_:)` [is documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avspeechsynthesizer/1619686-speak) to only "[add] the utterance you specify to the speech synthesizer’s queue"; the synthesizer doesn't necessarily start speaking right away, nor does the `speak(_:)` call wait until the synthesizer is done speaking before it returns.

In effect, `synthesizer.speak(utterance)` returns immediately, which signals your semaphore right away. (Because the call to `say` is also synchronous, this happens before you ever reach `sema.wait()`, which means the semaphore *could* never wait.) If this is the entirety of your code and you're running it as a script, the omission of `RunLoop.main.run()` means that your program also ends right away, and the synthesizer never gets the opportunity to speak. (The synthesizer prepares and plays the audio from a background thread, `speak(_:)` just kicks off the process; if the main thread exits without waiting, the whole program terminates and that background thread won't get to complete.)

To be informed of speech events (e.g., when the synthesizer starts and stops speaking), you'll need to create a type that conforms to the [`AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate) protocol, and set an instance of that type as the synthesizer's delegate. You can then respond to events as necessary.

---

As an aside, `DispatchSemaphore` is generally not recommended for synchronization purposes like this, because as an extremely low-level synchronization tool, it can lead to priority inversions (and if used incorrectly, very easily deadlock). If you expand on why you're trying to use a semaphore, we can give a more targeted suggestion on how to best replace it.

Comment: Thank you!  I will expand: how do I get the simple cmd-line app above to speak not using RunLoop.main.run(),  calling say("hello") more than once?

Comment: @user22491482 Is there a reason you're specifically trying to avoid `RunLoop`? In fact, spinning the main runloop is going to be the _easiest_ way to ensure that your program stays running long enough for the synthesizer to speak. The gist: create a delegate object that can be informed when the synthesizer has started/stopped speaking, enqueue the things you want for the synthesizer to say, then call `RunLoop.main.run()`; when the delegate receives a message that the last utterance has been spoken, you can halt the program successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call  `synthesizer.speak(utterance)`, it adds the utterance to the speech synthesizer’s queue and execute in async.

[image]

If you want to know when the speaking process is complete, you should set `synthesizer.delegate` and implement function `speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)`